# About Archimedean property

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Does the proposition ''If non empty set $S\subset \mathbb{Z}$ is bounded above (below), $S$ has a maximum (minimum) element.'' imply Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Have a look at this

Comment: https://books.google.com/books/about/Elementary_Number_Theory.html?id=2dI3AwAAQBAJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an ordered field $\Bbb F$ is not archimedean, then $S=\Bbb Z$ is bounded above (and below) and it has no maximum (nor minimum).

Comment: If $\mathbb{F}$ is not archimedean, there exist $a,b>0$ and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $na\leq b$. Then how can we conclude for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m\leq na$ only using axiom of orderd field? (or do you think another way?)

Comment: I'm using the axiom "An ordered field is Archimedean if and only if $\Bbb N$ is not bounded". Yours is its generalisation to totally ordered groups. They are equivalent, for fields, by means of the following argument: if $\Bbb N$ is bounded above by $m$, then the pair $a=1,\, b=m$ fails the latter; if $\Bbb Na$ is bounded above by $b$, then $\Bbb N$ is bounded above by $ba^{-1}$.